# How to custom mesage Double "Field must a number" in model blazor asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

======Model.cs=======

```
[MyCustomDoubleMessage(ErrorMessage = "Road length must be a number.")]
public double road_lenth {get; set;}
```

Without my custom atttribute, Default error message => "The road_length must a number."

Can I change default message like above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use  below attribute

```
[Display(Name = "Road length")]

[MyCustomDoubleMessage(ErrorMessage = "Road length must be a number.")]
public double road_lenth {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Write new custom attribute as below .**Change logic for double instead of not null**

```
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    private String displayName;

    public RequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "{0} is required";
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var attributes = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true);
        if (attributes != null)
            this.displayName = (attributes[0] as DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName;
        else
            this.displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(this.ErrorMessageString, displayName);
    } 
}
```

and model must be like below

```
[DisplayName("Road length")]
    [Required]
    public string road_lenth { get; set; }
```